# can I put multiple integers in a array value

Tags: arrays

If possible, **how can I put multiple integers in a array value?**
For ex.:

`$array = array((1,2),(5,6),(10,11,12));`

```
[0] => 1,2
[1] => 5,6
[2] => 10,11,12
```

Comment: I'm using PHP, can I just echo the array after that?

Comment: use php multidimensional arrays